# Debugging ERROR 000967 from standalone script?

Tags: arcpy, pythonwin

The following script is working in the Python window of ArcMap but not standalone in the PythonWin IDE:

```
   import arcpy
   from arcpy import env

   env.workspace = r"J:\Non_RS_MXDs\LongHaul.gdb"

   mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"J:\Non_RS_MXDs\RSF_Long_Haul.mxd")
   df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
   sourceLayer = r"J:\Non_RS_MXDs\Layer Files\Facility.lyr"
   for i in df:
       arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(i, sourceLayer)
   print "Done!"
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
    ERROR 000967: The input layer type must be a feature layer, raster layer, or tin layer.
    Failed to execute (ApplySymbologyFromLayer).
```

Answer (score 2):

you are currently listing dataframes, not layers (so i is your first dataframe). You should use something like

```
for i in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(i, sourcelayer)
```

Comment: Still not working. No errors are raised and the print statement executes but the layers in the map do not change.

Comment: @Shaun to persist the change in the MXD you created that map document object from you need an mxd.save() at the end.

Comment: Thanks. I got a "not enough storage space" error but then closed the map document, ran it, and all the symbols were changed when I reopened it. Anyway to get it to run while the map document is open?

Comment: @Shaun you said standalone which I would assume to mean in its own process with a guaranteed write available I.e. with no other process like ArcMap already holding a lock on that MXD.

Comment: @Shaun I agree with PolyGeo ! if you want to modify an open document, you should rather use the python script windows instead of a standalone script